# Cloudflare cookie is being reused by all sub domains

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-apps

We serve  a.example.com and b.example.com through cloudflare. Both use different Cloudflare access applications, Idp and different access policies to serve content through authorization.

when we go to a.example.com then we are taken to cloudflare login page. Logged in and page loads correctly.

when we go to b.example.com on the same laptop then it uses `CF_Authorization` cookie of a.example.com, renews this cookie, replaces `aud` with b.example.com access policy audience and returns the same cookie. It doesn't replaces claims, sub etc from a.example.com cookie. So it's breaking b.example.com.

Is it possible for a.example.com and b.example.com have different cookies altogether ? To achieve that what needs to be done ?

Comment: So each access policy specifies the given subdomain (a vs b), and there is no access policy that leaves the subdomain field empty, or a wildcard?

Comment: no. each access policy specifies subdomain a or b. only 2 access policies are there just to enforce authentication.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it sounds like from this thread this may be intended behavior - https://community.cloudflare.com/t/multiple-subdomain-behind-cloudflare-access-with-individual-authentication/251653

So the user only has to authenticate a single time, but then your authorization policies are purely for determining what that user has access to (not having separate authentication).

Comment: yea. i also thought it's default behaviour but i am just hoping there is way to break this behaviours.